# jQuery - using append() inside of a loop

Tags: jquery, loops, append, hierarchy

So I have a particular type of data structure that I'm trying to transform into a hierarchical list.  Codepen here: http://codepen.io/Metalyph/pen/NRGdLo?editors=1011

```
/* -------------------------------------------------- Example Variable */
var dataLayerArray = {
    length: 5,
    0: {
        id: 0,
        name: 'Layer 00',
        parentLayerId: -1,
        subLayerIds: [1,2,3]
    },
    1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Layer 01',
        parentLayerId: 0,
        subLayerIds: null
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Layer 02',
        parentLayerId: 0,
        subLayerIds: null
    },
    3: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Layer 03',
        parentLayerId: 0,
        subLayerIds: null
    },
    4: {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Layer 04',
        parentLayerId: -1,
        subLayerIds: null
    },
}


/* -------------------------------------------------- Heirarchy Loop */
for (var i = 0; i < dataLayerArray.length; i++) {
    var dataLayer = dataLayerArray[i];

    console.log('iteration ' + dataLayer.id);

    // DOM element added here
    $('#main_div ul').append('<li>'+dataLayer.name+'</li>');
    console.log('list item appended');

    if ( dataLayer.subLayerIds != null )
    {
        // this layer has children
        $('#main_div ul').append('<ul>');
        console.log('new list created');
    }
    else if
    (
        dataLayer.parentLayerId != -1
        &&
        dataLayer.parentLayerId != dataLayerArray[(dataLayer.id - 1)].id
        &&
        dataLayer.parentLayerId != dataLayerArray[(dataLayer.id + 1)].parentLayerId
    )
    {
        // this layer has a parent AND the previous layer is not the associated parent AND the next layer does not share the same parent
        $('#main_div ul').append('</ul>');
        console.log('list closed');
    }
    else
    {
        // layer has no children, and either has no parents or is a middle child
    }
}
```

The list should look like this:

- Layer 00

  - Layer 01
  - Layer 02
  - Layer 03
- Layer 04

Instead, using append(), it looks like this:

- Layer 00

  - Layer 01
  - Layer 02
  - Layer 03
  - Layer 04
- Layer 01
- Layer 02
- Layer 03
- Layer 04

If you look in the console of the codepen link, you can see the iterations of the list are working out as I intended.  I've also tried using after() and html( html() + 'string' ) but I end up with similarly strange results. Does append have some kind of behavior that i'm not understanding in this context?

Answer (score 0):

I would check if it doesn't have a parent to just add the element and if it has sublayers to add another list. If it has a parent then it can append to the list with the corresponding class.

```js
 /* -------------------------------------------------- Example Variable */
 var dataLayerArray = {
  length: 5,
  0: {
   id: 0,
   name: 'Layer 00',
   parentLayerId: -1,
   subLayerIds: [1,2,3]
  },
  1: {
   id: 1,
   name: 'Layer 01',
   parentLayerId: 0,
   subLayerIds: null
  },
  2: {
   id: 2,
   name: 'Layer 02',
   parentLayerId: 0,
   subLayerIds: null
  },
  3: {
   id: 3,
   name: 'Layer 03',
   parentLayerId: 0,
   subLayerIds: null
  },
  4: {
   id: 4,
   name: 'Layer 04',
   parentLayerId: -1,
   subLayerIds: null
  },
 }


 /* -------------------------------------------------- Heirarchy Loop */
 for (var i = 0; i < dataLayerArray.length; i++) {
  var dataLayer = dataLayerArray[i];

  if(dataLayer.parentLayerId == -1){
   $('#main_div .main').append('<li>'+dataLayer.name+'</li>');
   if(dataLayer.subLayerIds!=null){
    $('#main_div ul').append('<ul class="parent'+dataLayer.id+'"></ul>');
   }
  }else{
   $('#main_div ul ul[class="parent'+dataLayer.parentLayerId+'"]').append('<li>'+dataLayer.name+'</li>');
  }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_div">
 <ul class='main'>
  
 </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

If you sublayers don't always follow parent layers then you'd have two loops, one to get all the parents and one to get all the children:

```js
var dataLayerArray = {
  length: 5,
  0: {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Layer 00',
    parentLayerId: -1,
    subLayerIds: [1, 2, 3]
  },
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Layer 01',
    parentLayerId: 0,
    subLayerIds: null
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Layer 02',
    parentLayerId: 0,
    subLayerIds: null
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Layer 03',
    parentLayerId: 0,
    subLayerIds: null
  },
  4: {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Layer 04',
    parentLayerId: -1,
    subLayerIds: null
  },
}

for (var i = 0; i < dataLayerArray.length; i++) {
  var dataLayer = dataLayerArray[i];

  if (dataLayer.parentLayerId == -1) {
    $('#main_div .main').append('<li>' + dataLayer.name + '</li>');
    if (dataLayer.subLayerIds != null) {
      $('#main_div ul').append('<ul class="parent' + dataLayer.id + '"></ul>');
    }
  } 
}
for (var i = 0; i < dataLayerArray.length; i++) {
  var dataLayer = dataLayerArray[i];

  if (dataLayer.parentLayerId != -1) {
    
    $('#main_div ul ul[class="parent' + dataLayer.parentLayerId + '"]').append('<li>' + dataLayer.name + '</li>');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_div">
  <ul class='main'>

  </ul>
</div>
```